I could not print logo.png in any way
I want to send and print data to the Bluetooth device via TSPL for Android 13. Actually, those parts work, but I want to create a folder called LabelBasmaLogo under the files folder in the application's own directory and print the logo.png image in it, but no matter what I did, it did not work.
I think it's related to permissions. You tried different methods but it didn't work
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

namespace Etiket_basma
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private EditText dateEntry;
        private EditText weightEntry;
        private Spinner printerPicker;
        private Button printButton;
        private Button uploadLogoButton;
        private Android.Graphics.Bitmap logoBitmap;

        private const int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS = 1;
        private const int REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK = 2;
        private string logoFolderPath;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            InitializeUIComponents();
            RequestPermissions();
          
            dateEntry.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            dateEntry.Click += DateEntry_Click;

            LoadPairedPrinters();
            printButton.Click += PrintButton_Click;
           
        }

        private void InitializeUIComponents()
        {
            dateEntry = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.dateEntry);
            weightEntry = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.weightEntry);
            printerPicker = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.printerPicker);
            printButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.printButton);
            uploadLogoButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.selectImageButton);
        }

        private void RequestPermissions()
        {
            if (CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Bluetooth) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
                CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothAdmin) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
                CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
                CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
                CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
                CheckSelfPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestPermissions(new string[] {
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.Bluetooth,
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothAdmin,
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect,
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
                }, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }

        private void LoadPairedPrinters()
        {
            List<string> printers = GetPairedPrinters();
            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, printers);
            printerPicker.Adapter = adapter;
        }

        private void DateEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, OnDateSet, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);
            dialog.Show();
        }

        private void OnDateSet(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
        {
            dateEntry.Text = e.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }

        private List<string> GetPairedPrinters()
        {
            List<string> printerList = new List<string>();
            BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)GetSystemService(BluetoothService);
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;

            if (bluetoothAdapter == null)
            {
                ShowToast("Bluetooth desteği yok!");
                return printerList;
            }

            foreach (var device in bluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices)
            {
                printerList.Add(device.Name);
            }

            return printerList;
        }

        private async void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedPrinter = printerPicker.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            string date = dateEntry.Text;
            string weight = weightEntry.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(weight))
            {
                ShowToast("Lütfen Tarih ve Kilo girin!");
                return;
            }

            await PrintToBluetoothAsync(selectedPrinter, date, weight);
        }

        private async Task PrintToBluetoothAsync(string printerName, string date, string weight)
        {
            string address = GetPrinterAddress(printerName);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
            {
                ShowToast("Yazıcı adresi bulunamadı!");
                return;
            }

            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address);
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try
            {
                socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                await Task.Run(() => socket.Connect());

                string tsplData = GenerateTsplData(date, weight);
                byte[] logoData = logoBitmap != null ? ConvertBitmapToTspl(logoBitmap) : null;

                using (var outputStream = socket.OutputStream)
                {
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tsplData), 0, tsplData.Length);

                    if (logoData != null)
                    {
                        await outputStream.WriteAsync(logoData, 0, logoData.Length);
                    }

                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0x0A }, 0, 1); // Satır atla
                }

                ShowToast("Yazdırma işlemi başarılı!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowToast($"Yazdırma işlemi başarısız: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                socket?.Close();
            }
        }

        private string GenerateTsplData(string date, string weight)
        {
            return $"SIZE 72 mm, 38 mm\n" + // Etiket boyutu: 72mm genişlik, 38mm yükseklik
                   $"GAP 2 mm, 0 mm\n" + // Etiketler arasındaki boşluk
                   $"DENSITY 7\n" + // Yazıcı yoğunluğu
                   $"SET TEAR ON\n" + // Yırtma fonksiyonunu aç
                   $"CLS\n" + // Temizle
                   $"TEXT 01,60,\"40\",0,1,1,\"AYRO BILISIM HIZMETLERI\"\n" + // Şirket bilgisi
                   $"TEXT 01,120,\"58\",0,1,1,\"TARIH:{date}\"\n" + // Tarih
                   $"TEXT 01,190,\"50\",0,1,1,\"KILO:{weight} KG\"\n" + // Kilo
                   $"PRINT 1,1\n"; // Baskı
        }

        private string GetPrinterAddress(string printerName)
        {
            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

            if (bluetoothAdapter == null)
            {
                ShowToast("Bluetooth desteği yok!");
                return null;
            }

            foreach (BluetoothDevice device in bluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices)
            {
                if (device.Name == printerName)
                {
                    return device.Address; // Eşleşen yazıcının adresini döndür
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

      

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var uri = data.Data;
                logoBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, uri);
                string logoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "EtiketBasmaLogolar", "logo.png");

                using (var stream = new FileStream(logoPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    logoBitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
                }

                ShowToast("Logo yüklendi!");
            }
        }

        private byte[] ConvertBitmapToTspl(Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            // Bitmap'i siyah beyaz formata dönüştür
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap monochromeBitmap = ConvertToMonochrome(bitmap);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                monochromeBitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
                byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray(); // Burada imageBytes tanımlanıyor

                // TSPL komutları
                StringBuilder tsplData = new StringBuilder();
                tsplData.AppendLine($"BITMAP 0,0,{monochromeBitmap.Width},{monochromeBitmap.Height},1,{imageBytes.Length},0,0,0");

                // Bitmap'i ikili veriye dönüştürme
                foreach (byte b in imageBytes)
                {
                    tsplData.Append(b.ToString("X2")); // Her baytı hexadecimal formatta ekle
                }

                return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tsplData.ToString());
            }
        }




        private Android.Graphics.Bitmap ConvertToMonochrome(Android.Graphics.Bitmap original)
        {
            // Yeni monokrom bitmap oluştur
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap monochromeBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(original.Width, original.Height, Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

            for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
                {
                    // Orijinal pikseldan renk bilgisini al
                    int pixel = original.GetPixel(x, y);

                    // Pikselin gri tonunu hesapla
                    int gray = (int)(0.299 * Android.Graphics.Color.GetRedComponent(pixel) +
                                     0.587 * Android.Graphics.Color.GetGreenComponent(pixel) +
                                     0.114 * Android.Graphics.Color.GetBlueComponent(pixel));

                    // Monokrom pikseli ayarla
                    monochromeBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, gray, gray, gray));
                }
            }

            return monochromeBitmap;
        }

    

        private void ShowToast(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}

